# how to convert RGB-Image to 8bit Greyscale for imageJ plugin

Tags: java, imagej

I do really need to write a java code plugin for ImageJ for the following condition:

Transform an RGB-image with low contrast to an 8bit greyscale image in a way, that all greyscale values lie between 100 and 200

I really don't understand and can't find a good material as well. please help me

thank you :)

Comment: I'd suggest that you google and try out something before asking for direct answers here..
Please also refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask 
Try something and then when you are stuck and need help, ask specific questions ... then you have a better chance of getting answers

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23065325/java-for-imagej-how-to-convert-an-image-from-rgb-to-8-bit-using-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23065325/java-for-imagej-how-to-convert-an-image-from-rgb-to-8-bit-using-code)
This might be helpful